# jQuery .on() throws Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I cannot see this for looking.

mouseover works fine.
mouseout generates an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr").on("mouseover", function(){ highlightRow(); });
    $("tr").on("mouseout", "lowlightRow");
});

function highlightRow() {
    console.log("highlightRow");
}

function lowlightRow() {
    console.log("lowlightRow");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You passing a string "lowlightRow"

Comment: It's `$("tr").on("mouseout", lowlightRow);` and not `$("tr").on("mouseout", "lowlightRow");`. You should pass a `function`, not a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("tr").on("mouseout", lowlightRow);   // <-- passes function reference
```

not

```
$("tr").on("mouseout", "lowlightRow"); // <-- passes string
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass a function. Putting quotes around the function name makes it a string literal instead of a variable. Remove them.

```
$("tr").on("mouseout", lowlightRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $("tr").on("mouseout", "lowlightRow");
```

should be

```
   $("tr").on("mouseout", lowlightRow);
```